# Multiple comparisons in linear mixed models for several correlations, in R

Tags: r, correlation, mixed-model, repeated-measures

I am performing several correlations in R using the lme function, on a data set corresponding to the result of an experiment involving repeated measures. I would like to know whether some kind of test for multiple comparisons is available and appropriate. Do the p-values need to be somehow corrected with some sorts of adjustment?

Let's have a situation like this one:

```
library(nlme)
summary(lme(dv ~ factor1, data = My_data, random = ~1 | Subject))

summary(lme(dv ~ factor2, data = My_data, random = ~1 | Subject))

.....
.....

summary(lme(dv ~ factor20, data = My_data, random = ~1 | Subject))
```

As you can see there are 20 correlations. Do I need to perform some adjustment to the p-value or not?

A typical output of on of the correlations I am performing is the following:

```
summary(lme(dv ~ factor1, data = My_data, random = ~1 | Subject))
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: Concrete_sn 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  752.9427 763.8167 -372.4713

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | Subject
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    8.541603 5.113676

Fixed effects: Sound_Level_Peak ~ Virtual_BMI 
                Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept) -60.88944  8.892756 95 -6.847084   0.000
factor1   1.23015  0.409511 17  3.003959   0.008
 Correlation: 
            (Intr)
factor1 -0.974

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-2.39073241 -0.53497431  0.04460949  0.48231068  2.15453056 

Number of Observations: 114
Number of Groups: 19
```

Is that p-value fully significant (0.008) or do I need to adjust it?

Comment: I'm skeptical whether you should use separate models. Can you tell us more what these `factori` variables are?

Comment: In my experiment the variuos factor1, factor2.... factorN are measures of subjects anthropometric measures (e.g., weight, height, foot length) and perceived anthropometric measures (e.g. perceived weight, perceived height) and other evaluations they expressed, such as the degree of happiness, arousal or dominance they were feeling. The dv variables are measures of a task were subjects had to adjust some sounds moving some parameters of a sound model. For instance those variable are the centroid or the peak level of the sound. Why are you skeptical? Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems to me that your goal is identifying the factors that significantly influence your `dv`. Correct? Then you should consider that the factors probably work not independently but in conjunction and interaction.

Comment: Yes, thank you. How can I found out this? Can you please suggest an analysis and maybe a function in R?

Comment: Are you suggesting to use a formula like this one? summary(lme(dv ~ factor1*factor2*....factorN, data = My_data, random = ~1 | Subject))